# How to add widgets recursively to a flutter layout

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I would like to add buttons to a flutter screen by using a recursive loop function, how would I execute that?

Comment: Have a look on [ListView](https://youtu.be/KJpkjHGiI5A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<ElevatedButton> list = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: list,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            list.add(ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('One more'),
            ));
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That seems like it, but what if I want the button to be added to the list by an external function, outside the Widget build() function

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Extract the code inner the button and create a function.      setState(() {
            list.add(ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('One more'),
            ));
          });

Comment: Do you got it? Does this answer help you?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "function." in this case? Sorry, I am very new to this haha

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Recursive Model
class RecursiveModel {
  final String text;
  final List<RecursiveModel> children;

  RecursiveModel({required this.text, required this.children});
}

// Recursive Widget
class RecursiveWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final RecursiveModel model;

  RecursiveWidget({required this.model});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(model.text),
        SizedBox(height: 8),
        if (model.children.isNotEmpty)
          Column(
            children: model.children.map((child) {
              return RecursiveWidget(model: child);
            }).toList(),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

// Usage example
void main() {
  final RecursiveModel model = RecursiveModel(
    text: 'Parent',
    children: [
      RecursiveModel(
        text: 'Child 1',
        children: [],
      ),
      RecursiveModel(
        text: 'Child 2',
        children: [
          RecursiveModel(
            text: 'Grandchild',
            children: [],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );

  runApp(MyApp(model: model));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final RecursiveModel model;

  MyApp({required this.model});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Recursive Widget Example')),
        body: RecursiveWidget(model: model),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).